# full calendar call to google throws No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to use full calendar to embed my google calendar in my website. I have included the fullcalendar using bower and both the css and js files are in my index file. I also have the div included with id 'calendar'.

I followed the docs on http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

In my init.js file I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'myApiKey',
    eventSources: [
      {
        url: "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/mycalendarid/public/basic",
        dataType : 'jsonp'
      }
    ],
    eventClick: function(event) {
      // opens events in a popup window
      window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
      return false;
    }
  });
```

I also tried events instead of eventSources:

```
events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/mycalendarid/public/basic',
```

But I keep receiving the following error message:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/mycalendarid/public/basic?start=2015-04-26&end=2015-06-07&_=1431414654809. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

In the console I have my my api key with my referrers set to 'http://localhost:9000' so my origin should be okay. I also set my calendar public.

What else could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem today, and I found it was revolved after including `fullcalendar/gcal.js`.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
```

Detailed information please check the Dependencies section on [FullCalendar Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/).